# Call Equation Editor plugin when custom button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I have a very basic text editor that uses **CKEditor**. The default CKEditor toolbar is hidden because for editing I need only image upload (which is completely custom) and [Equation Editor plugin](http://ckeditor.com/addon/eqneditor) for formulas.

My goal is to use a custom button for the Equation Editor and call the plugin on click. So, somewhere in the UI of the editor, I would have this:

```
<a href="#" class="custom-formula-button">Insert formula</a>
```

Clicking on the button should open the Equation Editor.

**How do I achieve this?**

Note: I have multiple CKEditor instances on the page.

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`CKEDITOR.editor.execCommand()`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-method-execCommand) like this

```
CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorInstance.execCommand( 'mathjax' )
```

And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6348494/addeventlistener-vs-onclick) is where you'll find how to do this.

You can list available commands of the CKEditor instance by browsing `CKEDITOR.instances.myEditorInstance.commands` object.